# What is the most efficient way to create a folder with permissions in python (vs. running bash/shell commands)?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I'm converting some bash/shell scripts to Python.
I'd like to only create a directory/folder on a CentOS system if it doesn't exist already and then set 777 permissions on it.

I can easily do this with one command in bash:

```
mkdir -m 777 "/PATH/TO/DIRECTORY/GOES/HERE";
```

Right now i'm running this command as a subprocess in python, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner, faster, and/or more efficient way of doing it?

Any help or even hits will be appreciated! :)

Comment: Take a look at `os.mkdir` and `os.chmod`.

Comment: or you can set `os.umask(0000)` before creating the directory

Comment: you can take `os.mkdir`, `os.makedirs` and `os.system('your shell commands')` as the candidates.

In my dictionary, these commands are efficient enough :-), my favorite one is `os.makedirs`, since it help you making the parent folder(s) if not exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the permissions directly when using [os.mkdir](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkdir):

```
mkdir(...)
    mkdir(path [, mode=0777])

    Create a directory.
```

Comment: "If you want 777 you don't have to set it explicitly…" Not precisely. Keep in mind that the `mode` is modified by the process umask.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using os.mkdir and os.makedirs (as mentioned in @vicd's comment)